# how do i check the textcontent inside a button. the if statement isnt recognising the text

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, dom

[Linkedin search result](https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?keywords=ceo&origin=CLUSTER_EXPANSION&sid=D%3Ba)
so on the search page i want to only select the buttons with connect on them. the if statement doesnt seem to check if connect is the text content.

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('artdeco-button artdeco-button--2 artdeco-button--secondary ember-view')
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  console.log(buttons[i].textContent)
  if (buttons[i].textContent == 'Connect') {
    console.log(i)
  }

}
```

```html
<button aria-label="Invite x to connect" id="ember82" class="artdeco-button artdeco-button--2 artdeco-button--secondary ember-view"><!---->
    <span class="artdeco-button__text">
        Connect
    </span></button>
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zX9wu.png)
Shouldnt the connect have an corresponding i?

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML as we can't guess whethere there is more in there (a space maybe?).

Comment: you don't need to show Html code as you are doing web scraping.

Answer (score 2):

You are performing an exact match on the string `"Connect"` which fails because the `textContent` in your example also includes a bunch of whitespace.

You can use [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) to remove it before testing.

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('artdeco-button artdeco-button--2 artdeco-button--secondary ember-view')
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  console.log(buttons[i].textContent)
  if (buttons[i].textContent.trim() == 'Connect') {
    console.log(i)
  }

}
```

```html
<button aria-label="Invite x to connect" id="ember82" class="artdeco-button artdeco-button--2 artdeco-button--secondary ember-view"><!---->
    <span class="artdeco-button__text">
        Connect
    </span></button>
```